# How do I get pika to listen on priority queues first?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have 2 microservices that communicate via rabbitmq, I need to implement priority messages.

The first microservice acts as a publisher, written in symfony + messenger (amqp transport).

The second microservice acts as a consumer, written in python + pika.

The messenger documentation (https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#prioritized-transports) recommends using separate queues for different message priorities, this component is not able to use rabbitmq's built-in capabilities to prioritize messages. And actually there are no problems with the publisher, I configured it so that the necessary messages go to the priority queue.

Problems came with the consumer, I can't get pika to read the priority queue first, and then the regular one.

Here is an example of my messenger component configuration:

```
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            priority:
                dsn: "%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%"
                options:
                    exchange:
                        name: priority
                    queues:
                        priority: ~
            normal:
                dsn: "%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%"
                options:
                    exchange:
                        name: normal
                    queues:
                        normal: ~
        routing:
            'App\Message\PriorityRequest': priority
            'App\Message\NormalRequest': normal
```

This is how I fill the queues:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $bus->dispatch(new PriorityRequest($i, 'priority'));
    $bus->dispatch(new NormalRequest($i, 'normal'));
}
```

And here is an example of a consumer implementation in python + pika:

```
import pika
import os

def do_work(self, connection, channel, delivery_tag, body):
   print(body)


parameters = pika.URLParameters(os.getenv('MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN'))
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)

channel = connection.channel()
channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)

channel.queue_declare(queue='priority', durable=True)
channel.queue_declare(queue='normal', durable=True)

channel.basic_consume(queue='priority', on_message_callback=do_work, auto_ack=True)
channel.basic_consume(queue='normal', on_message_callback=do_work, auto_ack=True)

channel.start_consuming()
```

And if we run the consumer code, we get the following output:

```
{'id': 0, 'data': 'priority'}
{'id': 0, 'data': 'normal'}
{'id': 1, 'data': 'priority'}
{'id': 1, 'data': 'normal'}
{'id': 2, 'data': 'priority'}
{'id': 2, 'data': 'normal'}
{'id': 3, 'data': 'priority'}
{'id': 3, 'data': 'normal'}
{'id': 4, 'data': 'priority'}
{'id': 4, 'data': 'normal'}
{'id': 5, 'data': 'priority'}
{'id': 5, 'data': 'normal'}
{'id': 6, 'data': 'priority'}
{'id': 6, 'data': 'normal'}
{'id': 7, 'data': 'priority'}
{'id': 7, 'data': 'normal'}
{'id': 8, 'data': 'priority'}
{'id': 8, 'data': 'normal'}
{'id': 9, 'data': 'priority'}
{'id': 9, 'data': 'normal'}
```

Messages are processed in FIFO order, how do I force pika to process messages first from the priority queue and only if the priority queue is empty go to the normal queue?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by Pika out-of-the-box.

One option is to `basic_consume` from the priority queue first. When the queue is empty, cancel that consumer, and then `basic_consume` from the other queue. When that work is done, repeat and go back to the priority queue.